# TKinter - Clear text widget

Tags: text, tkinter, widget

I am inputting a random number from 1 to 25 into a text box on button press.
Every time i press the button, i want the text box to be emptied before the new number is stored - but putting `self.outputbox.delete("1.0")` into the button command only deletes the first character. i tried replacing 1.0 by something obvious like 2.0, but it never deleted both characters. At the moment, i am doing a very dirty solution by just calling `self.outputbox.delete("1.0")` twice - but i want to know how to delete the *entire* content of the text box.

this is the part:

```
   def change_button_color(self):
       randomcolor = self.get_random_color()
       randombutton = self.random_button()
       for z in range(0,1):
          self.buttons['button{}'.format(randombutton)].config(bg=randomcolor)
          for i in range(0,40):
              self.outputbox.delete("1.0")
          self.outputbox.insert("1.0","Button" + str(randombutton) + " " + "has the color" + " " + randomcolor)
```

as you can see, i currently have a rather dirty solution to clear the box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this

```
self.outputbox.delete("1.0", self.END)
```

it will clear all the text `widget`

And if you imported `tkinter as tk` do this

```
self.outputbox.delete("1.0", self.tk.END)
```

Comment: i tried that before, but the only thing that happened is "END" not defined error

Comment: what about `self.END`

Comment: that just changes it so saying that my class has no END attribute - do i have to declare END before in some way?

Comment: i did import it as tk and no, this one throws this: `AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'END'`

Comment: post small portion of it or create minimal

Comment: It's either `END` or `tk.END`, depending on your import. Alternatively, you can use the string `'end'`, since that is what the constant `END` contains anyway.

Comment: i see clear the widget before you loop through the range `placing the delete attribute on top of range` like `delete("1.0", tk.END)` then `for i in range(0,40):`

Comment: yes, just putting "end" or just tk.END worked - thanks both!

Comment: `self.tk.END` is bad advice, unless you also show in your example that `self.tk.END` must be defined. It's not automatically set by tkinter.