# Clear Text Widget for new text entry on every button press

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-text

I am trying to clear or reset a text box and store new results. Basically, every time i press the button, I would like the text box to be emptied before the new text is stored.

In my research the following thread popped up and he seems to have a similar goal however I wasn't sure how to apply that to my code. [TKinter - Clear text widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50581309/tkinter-clear-text-widget)

I've tried the following but it doesn't work for obvious reasons. Not sure how else to approach this.

```
button = tk.Button(root, command=lambda: button_cmmd())

def button_cmmd():
    if len(text_widget_1.get("1.0", "end-1c")) <= 5:
        #I get descriptions - this portion works.
    else:
        text_widget_2.delete("1.0", END)
```

EDIT
A half solution I've worked is:

```
def button_cmmd():
    if len(text_widget_2.get("1.0", "end-1c")) <= 2:
        text_widget_1.get("1.0", "end-1c"))
    else:
        text_widget_2.delete("1.0", "end-1c")
```

A minor annoyance now is that clicking the button once will populate the `text_box_2`, a 2nd click will delete that text so you have to click it a third time for it to run the `.get` again.

Comment: Why do you think the code doesn't work? I don't see any obvious reason why it wouldn't work.

Comment: @BryanOakley - The button works in two clicks however I was trying to make it clear any existing text and insert in 1 click.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Why not just remove the if statement and then run both functions?

Comment: @BryanOakley - Wow, I expected that to work originally but, when it didn't, I started looking for alternative solutions...... I must have had something else throwing it off I guess. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `tkinter.StringVar` object and pass it to the `textvariable` argument of the `tkinter.Entry()` call.

```py
entry_var = tkinter.StringVar(root, value="default value")
entry = tkinter.Entry(root, textvariable=entry_var)
button = tkinter.Button(root, text="Clear", command=lambda: clear_entry(entry_var))

entry.pack()
button.pack()

def clear_entry(var):
    var.set("")
```

To test it, I just ran it in IDLE:

```py
>>> import tkinter
>>> root = tkinter.Tk()
>>> entry_var = tkinter.StringVar(root, value="default value")
>>> def clear_entry(var):
    var.set("")

    
>>> entry = tkinter.Entry(root, textvariable=entry_var)
>>> button = tkinter.Button(root, text="Clear", command=lambda: clear_entry(entry_var))
>>> entry.pack()
>>> button.pack()
>>> root.mainloop()
```

Before clicking:

[image: Before]

After clicking:

[image: After]

Comment: Jacob Lee - My button text is "Generate" and is currently setup to ```.get``` the multiline text from text widget 1, process it, and insert it back into text widget 2. My question is how do I build the ability to clear the text in text box 2 within my same button. i.e. I just want it to clear text widget 2 first and then insert the new data on every button click.

Comment: In this case there's nothing you can do with a `StringVar` that you can't do directly with the entry widget. The introduction of the `StringVar` adds complexity but doesn't actually solve the problem.